# Password to Alter Contacts in a Microsoft Exchange Account

Tags: email, outlook, exchange-server, contacts

I have an exchange account shared to a team of people so that our contacts are always updated and in sync.

Is it possible to set a password when we try to alter the contacts? I'm having this issue where one person accidentally erases the one contact or the whole contact list and then my team gets their contacts deleted as well.

Comment: Offtopic, not  a programming question. We are not general server/Exchange tech support.

Comment: No, it is not possible. You can share the contacts folder with read only rights (not on Exchange side, but from Outlook) but this will genereally prevent from changing contacts.